# spark sql conditional maximum

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have a tall table which contains up to 10 values per group. How can I transform this table into a wide format i.e. add 2 columns where these resemble the value smaller or equal to a threshold?

I want to find the maximum per group, but it needs to be smaller than a specified value like:

```
min(max('value1), lit(5)).over(Window.partitionBy('grouping))
```

However `min()`will only work for a column and not for the Scala value which is returned from the inner function?

The problem can be described as:

```
Seq(Seq(1,2,3,4).max,5).min
```

Where `Seq(1,2,3,4)` is returned by the window.

How can I formulate this in spark sql?

## edit

E.g.

```
+--------+-----+---------+
|grouping|value|something|
+--------+-----+---------+
|       1|    1|    first|
|       1|    2|   second|
|       1|    3|    third|
|       1|    4|   fourth|
|       1|    7|        7|
|       1|   10|       10|
|      21|    1|    first|
|      21|    2|   second|
|      21|    3|    third|
+--------+-----+---------+
```

created by

```
case class MyThing(grouping: Int, value:Int, something:String)
val df = Seq(MyThing(1,1, "first"), MyThing(1,2, "second"), MyThing(1,3, "third"),MyThing(1,4, "fourth"),MyThing(1,7, "7"), MyThing(1,10, "10"),
MyThing(21,1, "first"), MyThing(21,2, "second"), MyThing(21,3, "third")).toDS
```

Where

```
df
.withColumn("somethingAtLeast5AndMaximum5", max('value).over(Window.partitionBy('grouping)))
.withColumn("somethingAtLeast6OupToThereshold2", max('value).over(Window.partitionBy('grouping)))
.show
```

returns

```
+--------+-----+---------+----------------------------+-------------------------+
|grouping|value|something|somethingAtLeast5AndMaximum5| somethingAtLeast6OupToThereshold2 |
+--------+-----+---------+----------------------------+-------------------------+
|       1|    1|    first|                          10|                       10|
|       1|    2|   second|                          10|                       10|
|       1|    3|    third|                          10|                       10|
|       1|    4|   fourth|                          10|                       10|
|       1|    7|        7|                          10|                       10|
|       1|   10|       10|                          10|                       10|
|      21|    1|    first|                           3|                        3|
|      21|    2|   second|                           3|                        3|
|      21|    3|    third|                           3|                        3|
+--------+-----+---------+----------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Instead, I rather would want to formulate:

```
lit(Seq(max('value).asInstanceOf[java.lang.Integer], new java.lang.Integer(2)).min).over(Window.partitionBy('grouping))
```

But that does not work as `max('value)` is not a scalar value.

Expected output should look like

```
+--------+-----+---------+----------------------------+-------------------------+
|grouping|value|something|somethingAtLeast5AndMaximum5|somethingAtLeast6OupToThereshold2|
+--------+-----+---------+----------------------------+-------------------------+
|       1|    4|   fourth|                           4|                        7|
|      21|    1|    first|                           3|                     NULL|
+--------+-----+---------+----------------------------+-------------------------+
```

### edit2

When trying a pivot

```
df.groupBy("grouping").pivot("value").agg(first('something)).show
+--------+-----+------+-----+------+----+----+
|grouping|    1|     2|    3|     4|   7|  10|
+--------+-----+------+-----+------+----+----+
|       1|first|second|third|fourth|   7|  10|
|      21|first|second|third|  null|null|null|
+--------+-----+------+-----+------+----+----+
```

The second part of the problem remains that some columns might not exist or be null.

When aggregating to arrays:

```
df.groupBy("grouping").agg(collect_list('value).alias("value"), collect_list('something).alias("something"))
+--------+-------------------+--------------------+
|grouping|              value|           something|
+--------+-------------------+--------------------+
|       1|[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10]|[first, second, t...|
|      21|          [1, 2, 3]|[first, second, t...|
+--------+-------------------+--------------------+
```

The values are already next to each other, but the right values need to be selected. This is probably still more efficient than a join or window function.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data and the problem you want to solve?

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Can you add the _expected outout_ for the specific sample data that you've added?

Comment: Please see the expected output. I would like to avoid a self join if possible.

Answer (score 3):

Would be easier to do in two separate steps - calculate `max` over Window, and then use `when...otherwise` on result to produce `min(x, 5)`:

```
df.withColumn("tmp", max('value1).over(Window.partitionBy('grouping)))
  .withColumn("result", when('tmp > lit(5), 5).otherwise('tmp))
```

**EDIT**: some example data to clarify this:

```
val df = Seq((1, 1),(1, 2),(1, 3),(1, 4),(2, 7),(2, 8))
  .toDF("grouping", "value1")

df.withColumn("result", max('value1).over(Window.partitionBy('grouping)))
  .withColumn("result", when('result > lit(5), 5).otherwise('result))
  .show()

// +--------+------+------+
// |grouping|value1|result|
// +--------+------+------+
// |       1|     1|     4| // 4, because Seq(Seq(1,2,3,4).max,5).min = 4
// |       1|     2|     4|
// |       1|     3|     4|
// |       1|     4|     4|
// |       2|     7|     5| // 5, because Seq(Seq(7,8).max,5).min = 5
// |       2|     8|     5|
// +--------+------+------+
```

Comment: So actually I have a tall table with lets say 1....10 per group and for the values 5 and 8 I want to extract the value of the columns something into a wide format i.e. append 2 columns. Your solution will only apply the global max wich in most times will result in 10. Note: not all values 1...10 are present, sometimes there are null values. That's why if i.e. 5 and 8 are not available I want to take the next smaller value available.

Comment: Your solution would mostly work fine for part b) i.e. the group with the larger values for 8. But then, if the maximum is 10 we would take the min (10,8). This could be a problem, as 8 might not exist. In this case I would want to take the next smallest value i.e. 7 if it exists. If not the next one. If that is smaller than the boundary i.e. 5, None should be the result.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following; This answers the original post, which states it should calculate the DataFrame equivalent of `Seq(Seq(<values matching group>).max,5).min`. You might have to rephrase the post entirely or post a new question, I can't correlate your comments here to the original post...

Comment: I will try to rephrase.